# mysql service stops while trying to alter a table

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mysql-workbench

I have mysql 5.1 installed using this: mysql-essential-5.1.49-win32.msi.
And also have Workbench installed using this mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.26-win32.msi
On Windows 7

Now my problem that anytime i try to create a new table or alter an exist table, the mysql service stops and workbench gives an error that it can't connect. But before the service stops i can show any table data, the problem happen when trying to alter or create new table.

I removed mysql and workbench and intalled again and restarted my machine, but the same error appear.

Also one more thing:
In visual studio 2010 i can't expand the database to see tables it also stops the service :(.

How to know what's the problem and how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your server error log:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

The file should be called host_name.err in your data directory.